# Android unable to close due to unfinalized statements or unfinished backups (code 5): Count not close db

Tags: android, database, sqlite, exception

I'm starting my journey as a coder in Android Development. Please excuse me if the error is too simple. 
I'm facing an issue with the SQLite Database that I am creating and I'm not able to solve it.

```
I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 48228(1684KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 2MB/4MB, paused
6.769ms total 25.319ms I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 56325(1885KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 40% free, 2MB/4MB, paused 9.877ms total 33.077ms I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 56480(1897KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(328KB) LOS objects, 40% free, 2MB/4MB, paused 10.284ms total
36.064ms I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 49608(1660KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 2MB/4MB, paused 13.506ms total 44.492ms I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 49621(1661KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 2MB/4MB, paused 13.629ms total 49.390ms I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 49640(1662KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 2MB/4MB, paused
19.149ms total 54.527ms I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 49720(1664KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 2MB/4MB, paused 17.575ms total 56.892ms E/SQLiteConnection: sqlite3_close(0x7f3b5dd15280) failed: 5 E/SQLiteConnectionPool: Failed to close connection, its fate is now in the hands of the merciful GC: SQLiteConnection: /data/user/0/com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder/databases/medicine.db (0)
                        android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: unable to close due to unfinalized statements or unfinished backups (code 5): Count not close db.
                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeClose(Native Method)
                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.dispose(SQLiteConnection.java:238)
                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.close(SQLiteConnection.java:203)
                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.closeConnectionAndLogExceptionsLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:528)
                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.closeAvailableConnectionsAndLogExceptionsLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:501)
                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.dispose(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:226)
                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.close(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:205)
                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.dispose(SQLiteDatabase.java:295)
                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.onAllReferencesReleased(SQLiteDatabase.java:272)
                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.releaseReference(SQLiteClosable.java:74)
                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.close(SQLiteClosable.java:106)
                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:277)
                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
                            at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.addMedicineActivity.save(addMedicineActivity.java:145)
                            at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.addMedicineActivity.access$300(addMedicineActivity.java:26)
                            at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.addMedicineActivity$2.onClick(addMedicineActivity.java:100)
                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 57379(9MB) AllocSpace objects, 12(6MB) LOS objects, 0% free, 34MB/34MB, paused 598us total 108.933ms W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder/databases/medicine.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed. E/SQLiteConnection: sqlite3_close(0x7f3b5dd15280) failed: 5 E/System: Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer E/System: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: unable to close due to unfinalized statements or unfinished backups (code 5): Count not close db.
              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeClose(Native Method)
              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.dispose(SQLiteConnection.java:238)
              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.finalize(SQLiteConnection.java:178)
              at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:202)
              at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:185)
              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) W/art: Suspending all threads took: 11.514ms I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 29721(4MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 80MB/80MB, paused 11.913ms total 25.311ms E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder, PID: 7791
                  java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
                      at java.lang.CaseMapper.toUpperCase(CaseMapper.java:147)
                      at java.lang.String.toUpperCase(String.java:1158)
                      at android.database.DatabaseUtils.getSqlStatementType(DatabaseUtils.java:1399)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:890)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1674)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1605)
                      at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:39)
                      at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
                      at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
                      at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
                      at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
                      at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
                      at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
                      at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
                      at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
                      at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
                      at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
                      at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
                      at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
                      at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
                      at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
                      at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
                      at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
                      at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
                      at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
                      at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
                      at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
                      at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
                      at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
                      at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
                      at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
                      at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
                      at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
                      at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
                      at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
                    at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLi D/Error: ERR: exClass=java.lang.StackOverflowError D/Error: ERR: exMsg=stack size 8MB D/Error: ERR: file=CaseMapper.java D/Error: ERR: class=java.lang.CaseMapper D/Error: ERR: method=toUpperCase line=147 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 17.524ms D/Error: ERR: stack=java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
             at java.lang.CaseMapper.toUpperCase(CaseMapper.java:147)
             at java.lang.String.toUpperCase(String.java:1158)
             at android.database.DatabaseUtils.getSqlStatementType(DatabaseUtils.java:1399)
             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:890)
             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1674)
             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1605)
             at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:39)
             at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
             at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
             at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
             at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
             at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
             at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
             at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
             at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
             at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
             at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
             at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
             at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
             at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
             at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
             at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
             at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
             at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
             at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
             at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
             at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
             at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
             at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
             at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
             at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
             at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
             at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
             at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
             at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
             at com.dankildev.mymedicationreminder.DataBase.MedicineSQLiteHelper.onCreate(MedicineSQLiteHelper.java:40)
            at com.dankildev.mymedicat D/Error: ERR: TOTAL BYTES WRITTEN: 16144400 E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 16144492) E/AndroidRuntime: Error reporting crash
                  android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 16144492 bytes
                      at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                      at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
                      at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.handleApplicationCrash(ActivityManagerNative.java:4425)
                      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:90)
                      at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
                      at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
```

That's the error that appears when I try to create and add data to my Database table. 
The code I run is the following:

```
MedicineSQLiteHelper mMedicineSQLiteHelper = new MedicineSQLiteHelper(this);

        SQLiteDatabase db = mMedicineSQLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MedEntry.COLUMN_MED_NAME, medicamentName);
        values.put(MedEntry.COLUMN_DOSAGE, dosage);
        values.put(MedEntry.COLUMN_ICON_ID, icon);
        values.put(MedEntry.COLUMN_NUMBER_OF_HOURS, Integer.parseInt(numberOfHours));
        values.put(MedEntry.COLUMN_HOURS_DAYS, hourDaySpinnerContent);
        values.put(MedEntry.COLUMN_HOURS, hourSelected);
        values.put(MedEntry.COLUMN_MINUTES, minuteSelected);
        values.put(MedEntry.COLUMN_DAY, day);
        values.put(MedEntry.COLUMN_MONTH, month);
        values.put(MedEntry.COLUMN_YEAR, year);

        long newRowId = db.insert(MedEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
```

The MedicineSQLiteHelper class is the following:

```
public class MedicineSQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DB_NAME = "medicine.db";
private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

public MedicineSQLiteHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String SQL_CREATE_MEDS_TALBE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + MedEntry.TABLE_NAME + " ( "
            + MedEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
            + MedEntry.COLUMN_MED_NAME + " TEXT ,"
            + MedEntry.COLUMN_DOSAGE + " TEXT ,"
            + MedEntry.COLUMN_ICON_ID + " INTEGER ,"
            + MedEntry.COLUMN_NUMBER_OF_HOURS + " INTEGER ,"
            + MedEntry.COLUMN_HOURS_DAYS + " TEXT ,"
            + MedEntry.COLUMN_HOURS + " INTEGER ,"
            + MedEntry.COLUMN_MINUTES + " INTEGER ,"
            + MedEntry.COLUMN_DAY + " INTEGER ,"
            + MedEntry.COLUMN_MONTH + " INTEGER ,"
            + MedEntry.COLUMN_YEAR + " INTEGER );";

    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_MEDS_TALBE);
    onCreate(db);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
}
```

My understanding tells me this is an issue related to not having closed a cursor?

I hope I've added all the necessary information, if anyone code provide me with some code explaining me the error, I would highly appreciate it! :)